# Not activating Mandatory Access Control as /sbin/tomoyo-init does not exist?

Tags: linux

When I compiled the Linux kernel to generate `bzImage`, created `rootfs` using `busybox`, and restarted my computer to execute `dmesg`, I found an alarm. The executable file `tomoyo-init` is not available in my customized system `/sbin`, but my other computer has `debian12` installed, and it is the same. May I ask what's going on?

Some information about `dmesg`:

```
...
[    5.881333] usb 1-4.4: Manufacturer: CoreChips
[    5.881334] usb 1-4.4: SerialNumber: 000000000012
[    5.994649] usb 1-8: new full-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[    6.121406] usb 1-8: New USB device found, idVendor=2c42, idProduct=1709, bcdDevice= 0.02
[    6.121409] usb 1-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    6.121411] usb 1-8: Product: USB TO CANBUS BRIDGE
[    6.121412] usb 1-8: Manufacturer: FINTEK
[    6.121413] usb 1-8: SerialNumber: 88635600168801
[    6.129607] asix 1-1:1.0 enx000ec6942ec8: renamed from eth0
[    6.136120] asix 1-6:1.0 enx000ec6942ec9: renamed from eth1
[    6.421936] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p3): mounted filesystem c77a9130-f6eb-4eb6-aa9a-b20f388ab0e6 r/w with ordered data mode. Quota mode: none.
[    6.464134] Not activating Mandatory Access Control as /sbin/tomoyo-init does not exist.
[    6.510129] dca service started, version 1.12.1
[    6.530192] pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
[    6.530197] pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
[    6.547368] PTP clock support registered
[    6.630436] igb: Intel(R) Gigabit Ethernet Network Driver
[    6.630442] igb: Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Intel Corporation.
[    6.630496] igb 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    6.660066] pps pps0: new PPS source ptp0
[    6.660132] igb 0000:01:00.0: added PHC on eth0
[    6.660134] igb 0000:01:00.0: Intel(R) Gigabit Ethernet Network Connection
[    6.660136] igb 0000:01:00.0: eth0: (PCIe:2.5Gb/s:Width x1) 90:e4:68:02:01:40
[    6.660138] igb 0000:01:00.0: eth0: PBA No: FFFFFF-0FF
...
```

I saw some people online saying it's related to `grub.cfg`. The `grub.cfg` in my customization system is as follows:

```
root@dobot:~# cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg
# Begin cfg
set default=0
set timeout=3

menuentry "GNU/Linux, Dobot-6.4.0-rt8" {
    linux (hd0,gpt2)/bzImage rw root=/dev/mmcblk0p3 net.ifname-policy=onboard,path,slot
    initrd (hd0,gpt2)/initrd.img-6.4.0-rt8
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn’t an “alarm”, it’s just a message indicating that [the TOMOYO Linux MAC subsystem](https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/LSM/tomoyo.html) wasn’t activated, because user-space activation was configured but `/sbin/tomoyo-init` wasn’t available.

See [the relevant kernel configuration](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.7.1/source/security/tomoyo/Kconfig#L2) for details: it seems you enabled `SECURITY_TOMOYO`, without `SECURITY_TOMOYO_OMIT_USERSPACE_LOADER`, and didn’t provide the required user-space tools.

If you’re not going to use TOMOYO Linux you should disable `SECURITY_TOMOYO` in your build configuration. If you are going to use it, you should provide the appropriate tools (the `tomoyo-tools` package in Debian) and configuration.

Comment: Will it improve system performance if I close `TOMOYO Linux`?

Comment: It won’t make much difference — when it’s disabled at runtime, it’s as is it isn’t there, apart from the memory footprint. As a general rule however, if you’re building your own kernel, you should only include features you intend to use. The kernel binary has to be fully loaded into memory, and can’t be swapped out, so any code it includes that doesn’t get used is wasted space.